# Why OData Web API returns JSON only

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, json, odata

This is weird! I create OData Web API with ASP.NET MVC 5. Return IQueriable from the controller, nothing special.

But in some reason **it constantly returns JSON when I need XML**.

I send GET from Fiddler with **Accept: application/xml** - no reaction.

I try to force **removing JsonFormater** in the server code - no reaction again.

It always returns JSON. What do I miss?

Comment: have you tried - application/atom+xml?

Comment: You helped! Thank you very much.

Comment: In some reason application/xml doesn't work, but application/atom+xml does

Comment: It is odata V3 supports only three protocols. And in one protocal for atom, you misspelled it. Can I make it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with - **Accept: application/atom+xml**.

AFAIK in OData V3 there are three protocals ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015473/web-api-odataresult-is-always-serializing-to-atom)) -

1. Atom (application/atom+xml)
2. JSON Verbose (application/json;odata=verbose)
3. JSON Light (application/json;odata=light)