# Odata v4 always returns JSON , I need xml result

Tags: json, xml, odata

I have tried with all the approaches of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336879/why-odata-web-api-returns-json-only), but still it returns always in JSON format. In `WepApi.config` I have added the below lines and tried with `?$format=atom` and  `?$format=xml`.

```
var odataFormatters = ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create();
config.Formatters.InsertRange(0, odataFormatters);
```

In fiddler I'm able to see the below formats:

```
Accept:text/html, application/xhtml+xml,*/*
```

Could you please suggest me where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simple response can be: "Web API OData V4 always return JSON because JSON is standard while Atom is not now. See [OData.Org](http://www.odata.org/documentation/)"